# Initial administrator log in to horde

Tags: email, debian, mysql

I have installed horde webmail on my debian wheezy machine using the jessie packages and this guide: https://wiki.debian.org/Horde

I have set up a database skeleton in mysql - just created a `horde` database and a `horde` user to access it - and I have run webmail install.

No, to continue configuring horde, all the guides I find say that I should go to the `administrator` tab and do the settings. Where do I find that? When I point my web browser to the hostname of my machine, I get a login screen, and no matter what I write I can't log in. I have tried my unix user name and password, and I have tried the horde user name and password, but I only get `Error connecting to mail server.` back.

I feel I am missing something obvious - but what?

Answer (score 0):

From the [online documentation](http://wiki.horde.org/FAQ/Admin/Config#toc14):

> **What are the default user name and password for the administrator?**
>
> There are none. Since Horde supports a broad variety of different authentication backends and you are free to choose any of them for your Horde installation, the selected backend decides which are valid login credentials. And we didn't add an authentication independent backdoor to Horde, for obvious reasons.
> Instead, you can turn any valid and authenticated user into an administrator by adding his user name to the administrator list in Horde's configuration. Make sure to use user names exactly like they are used inside Horde, i.e. with or without a domain name, and considering any user name hooks that you enabled.

To do this, edit the `/config/config.php` file adding the following line:

```
$conf['auth']['admins'] = array('your_admin_user');
```

This should allow you to login. From there, you should be able to configure everything else.

Comment: Than you for your reply. Yes, I found that as well, but what does it mean? When I try to find documentation on how to install an authentication backend, I get pointed back to the `administrator` tab that I can't access - because I don't have am authentication backend. So the question still stands - how do I get there the fist time? What is the _initial_ authentication back end? Or how do I install the initial authentication backend?

Comment: @Bex I am not very familiar with horde, but I have updated my answer. I believe you can configure everything **after** doing this initial step, which will allow you to access all the configuration sections.

Comment: Thank you! I came that far - so I do have my user name in the conf.php-file - but I can't log in, because there is no back end to authenticate the user. I mean - I write a name in the `your_admin_user` slot, but what password will that user name have? How will it be authenticated? I write the name of my unix user, but the unix password doesn't work. I have tried adding the mysql user name of horde and tried logging in with the corresponding (mysql) password, but that doesn't work either.